# Add external JS file in component to render images in browser with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I make a site with Angular 2 and will add a JavaScript file to the component. This script must render the height of some images equal to the height of the window of the browser.

How could I add this script to the component?

The solutions I found on SO or anywhere else, looks like this:

```
import './home.component.js';
```

But it's not what I need! I need this in my `home.component.ts` file:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
    jsUrls: ['./home.component.js']
})
```

or something...

**Update 1:** In my site I use Angular CLI and TypeScript.

**Update 2:** You could find my project on GitHub: https://github.com/WatchFriends/Web

Comment: The way to do that is adding the script to your index.html, then in your home.component.ts import the definition of that myScript.js if you have a definition, if not just add declare var myScript; and then access to the functions with myScript.myFunction(...);

Comment: What are you using to build your project? The CLI has a way to do this, and webpack does as well. There's the script_loader loader which adds it to the bundle, and so on. Need to know a little more about your buildout.

Comment: @TimConsolazio: Yes I use Angular CLI

Comment: I think then you just use the "script" array of the angular-cli.json file. 

"scripts": [ "path_to_file/file.js" ]

In webpack, you can use script_loader directly (I do this and it's easy). But I think the CLI intentionally hides webpack complexity from you.

Comment: @TimConsolazio: no I've got this error: `Argument of type '{ templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[]; script: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.` by using `script` or `scripts`.

Comment: Think I'd need to see what you're doing. In fact I'll try it in one of my own Ang2 CLI projects and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, and works well:

In the angular-cli.json file, there is a section, "scripts". Add the path to your script in that array (as a double-quoted string).

Here's a frag from that file:

```
  "mobile": false,
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": ["./app/my_script.js"],
  "environments": {
    "source": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```

my_script is this:

```
function sayHello ( ) {
   console.log ( 'I am saying hello' );
}
```

Then just call it like you'd expect from anywhere. To beat the annoying "not found" error you may get in your IDE, you can either just do this:

```
window [ 'sayHello' ] ( );
```

Or create a utility class that contains a reference to that function, such that you can import the class and call the function as usual (you are basically just providing a framework facade for your "my_script.js" functions).

I tried both, it worked just fine, no errors (you are using ng serve or ng build of course etc).

Comment: I turned it into one of my Ang2 articles, look under "errata":

http://www.tcoz.com/